# Don't know what's wrong with my IF statement (JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to make a number guessing game where the user gets 3 chances to guess a number between 1 to 10 and after the third try if they don't manage to guess the number correctly, they'll lose and the number input becomes **disabled**.

So my variable "tryNum" is meant to be the number of guesses the user gets which I set to be 3. And I then wrote my if statement whereby every time the user guesses the number incorrectly, the value of tryNum decreases by 1. And based on my code, by the time the user guesses 3 incorrect numbers, the input should become disabled and an error message should be displayed. However, when I run my code, it takes 4 incorrect guesses instead of 3 for my code to execute.

I am not sure why this is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
let min = 1,
    max = 10,
    winningNum = 3;
    tryNum = 3;

function btnClciked(){
  guessedNum = parseInt(userInput.value);
  if (tryNum > 0){
    let status;
    if (isNaN(guessedNum) || guessedNum < min || guessedNum > max ){
      if(document.querySelector(".error-display")){
        status = false;
      } else {
        status = true;
      }
      isNaN(guessedNum) ? createDivElement("You havn't entered any number!", status, "#eb992d","black", true) : createDivElement(`You must guess a number between ${min} and ${max}`, status, "#eb992d", "black", true);  
    } 
    else if (guessedNum === winningNum){
      status = true;
      userInput.disabled = true;
      userInput.style.borderColor = "green";
      submitBtn.value = "Play Again!";
      submitBtn.className += "play-again";
      createDivElement(`Congratulations! You guessed the winning number: ${winningNum} Correctly!`, status, "green", "white");
    } 
    else {
      status = true;
      userInput.style.borderColor = "red";
      userInput.value = "";
      tryNum -= 1;
      createDivElement(`${guessedNum} isn't the winning number! You have ${tryNum} more guesses left!`, status, "red", "white");
    } 
  } else {
    userInput.disabled = true;
    status = true;
    userInput.style.borderColor = "red";
    submitBtn.value = "Play Again!";
    submitBtn.className += "play-again";
    createDivElement(`Game Over! The winning number was ${winningNum}.`, status, "red", "white");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user guesses it wrong, you should check if `tryNum` is equal to `0`, in which case you should show that it is Game Over.

```
function btnClciked(){
  guessedNum = parseInt(userInput.value);
  if (tryNum > 0){
    let status;
    if (isNaN(guessedNum) || guessedNum < min || guessedNum > max ){
      if(document.querySelector(".error-display")){
        status = false;
      } else {
        status = true;
      }
      isNaN(guessedNum) ? createDivElement("You havn't entered any number!", status, "#eb992d","black", true) : createDivElement(`You must guess a number between ${min} and ${max}`, status, "#eb992d", "black", true);  
    } 
    else if (guessedNum === winningNum){
      status = true;
      userInput.disabled = true;
      userInput.style.borderColor = "green";
      submitBtn.value = "Play Again!";
      submitBtn.className += "play-again";
      createDivElement(`Congratulations! You guessed the winning number: ${winningNum} Correctly!`, status, "green", "white");
    } 
    else {
      status = true;
      userInput.style.borderColor = "red";
      userInput.value = "";
      tryNum -= 1;
      if(tryNum != 0){
          createDivElement(`${guessedNum} isn't the winning number! You have ${tryNum} more guesses left!`, status, "red", "white");
      } else {
        userInput.disabled = true;
        status = true;
        userInput.style.borderColor = "red";
        submitBtn.value = "Play Again!";
        submitBtn.className += "play-again";
        createDivElement(`Game Over! The winning number was ${winningNum}.`, status, "red", "white");
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do understand your code. But could you possibly explain why my code was wrong?

Comment: @m3hran Your code was wrong because you would display "0 tries left" instead of "Game Over". When the user guesses wrong, you need to check if they still have more tries left.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you don't guess the number the third time the value of tryNum is 0 but you have to make another guess in order to trigger the first if statement and enter in the final else block.
The simplest solution is to put the final else block into an if statement below `tryNum-=1` to check if the variable is 0